# Print out list item display form (InfoPath)

Tags: infopath, list-item, display-form, printing

I have a SharePoint site used for tracking despatches in a warehouse. I think I'm going to use InfoPath to design the form to make it look nice, rather than CSS or JS, and from what I've seen elsewhere, different solutions exist for standard and InfoPath forms(?).

I just want to be able to select an item from the list and have the option to print the form.

I'd like the solution to be as simple as possible if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ribbon of List Form you could add a action "Print". And the Command Action for that could be set as below

```
CommandAction='javascript:window.print()'
```